# How to Calculate Previous Rows Balance in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have a Amount Transaction table which contains the following data's:

[image]

First Thing I Display Balance Amount.

[image]

Controller Code

```
 $invaccountstatements = DB::table('tranactions')->whereDate('date', '>=', '2016-06-09')
    ->whereDate('date', '<=', '2016-06-20')->get();
```

Blade Code

```
     @foreach($invaccountstatements as $invaccstatements)
     <tr>
    <td>{{$invaccstatements->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$invaccstatements->acc_date}}</th>
    <td>{{$invaccstatements->description}}</th>
    <td style="text-align:right;">  {{number_format($invaccstatements->acc_credit, session('digitsformat'))}}   </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">{{number_format($invaccstatements->acc_debit, session('digitsformat'))}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php $chkbala = $invaccstatements->acc_credit - $invaccstatements->acc_debit; $tbalance += $chkbala;
    echo number_format($tbalance, session('digitsformat'));?></td>
     </tr> 
   @endforeach
```

Next I add From Date and To Date Search Filter for this Table.

I Search From Date (09-06-16) to To Date (20-06-16).

I Need Laravel Query which gives Following Result.

[image]

Comment: Please share your try, wrong result , the query which not works ? without query its not clear to us.

Comment: @Niklesh I wrote query for to display Balance amount. i have no idea to calculate Opening Balance (Previous Rows Balance Amount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the query to get all the data, now simply add `whereDate()`.

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereDate('date', '>=', '2016-06-09')
->whereDate('date', '<=', '2016-06-20')
->get();
```

Using your beloved query builder

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
->whereDate('date', '>=', '2016-06-09')
->whereDate('date', '<=', '2016-06-20')
->get();
```

**Balance on start date**

```
$beforeFirstDay = DB::table('transactions')
->whereDate('date', '<=', '2016-06-09')
->get();

//do the same loop you and your friend were doing to calculate the balance
//It will give you starting balance

$originalBalance = 0;
foreach( $beforeFirstDay as $day ) {
    $originalBalance = $originalBalance + ($day->credit - $day->debit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @EddyTheDove I Need How to Calculate Opening Balance (Previous Rows Balance)

Comment: It would drastically be easier for you (and your friends/classmates) if you saved `balance` in a table. But since you don't, you will have to query EVERYSINGLE line that occurs before start date.